# Conditional Probability Equivalence

Tags: probability

I am reading this paper here: http://www.utm.utoronto.ca/~weisber3/articles/SobervBJPS3.SP.pdf which claims on page 10 that $p(E \wedge [H_x \wedge \sim R]) + p(E \wedge [H_x \wedge E])= p(H_x \wedge E)$. I am having trouble seeing this equivalence.

Any help is appreciated; thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't.  That step is erroneous, as is the one prior (the sum-rule is only valid when the two events are mutually exclusive, which they clearly are not).

However, both are also unnecessary, as: $[E\wedge [H_x\wedge \neg R]] \vee [E\wedge [H_x\wedge E]]) = E\wedge H_x$ , thus you immediately have the desired result.

$$p([E\wedge [H_x\wedge \neg R]] \vee [E\wedge [H_x\wedge E]])
\\[2ex] = p([[E\wedge H_x]\wedge \neg R]\vee [[E\wedge H_x]\wedge E]) 
\\[2ex] = p([[E\wedge H_x]\wedge \neg R]\vee [E\wedge H_x]) 
\\[2ex] = p([E\wedge H_x]) 
$$

Comment: There is some confusion in your response. You say that the step is erroneous however you say that $[E∧[H_x∧\sim R]]∨[E∧[H_x∧E]]) = E∧H_x$ does hold. However, this is equivalent to exactly the sequence of equalities which you have given.

So which is it - do you think that the equality which I am asking about is erroneous or is it redundant? It cannot be both.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether   It's a case of two wrongs accidentally make a right.  The author knew where to go but wandered off on a false path to get there. $$p([E\wedge [H_x\wedge\neg R]] \vee [E\wedge [H_x\wedge E]]) \underbrace{\neq p(E\wedge [H_x\wedge \neg R]) + p(E\wedge[H_x\wedge E]) \neq}_{\text{but ignore this as the end terms are equal to each other}} p(E\wedge H_x)$$$$p([E\wedge [H_x\wedge\neg R]] \vee [E\wedge [H_x\wedge E]]) = p(E\wedge H_x)$$

Comment: I do not accept that the first inequality is an inequality; $\sim R$ and $E$ are probabilistically independent so it is a valid inference to conclude that $p([E\wedge [H_x\wedge\neg R]] \vee [E\wedge [H_x\wedge E]]) \underbrace = p(E\wedge [H_x\wedge \neg R]) + p(E\wedge[H_x\wedge E])$. How is the first inequality an inequality?

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether That is for **mutually exclusive** events (also known as *disjoint* events). It is *not* the case for independent events; where in fact: $$p(A\vee B) = p(A)+p(B)-p(A\wedge B) \\ \mathop{=}^{\text{ind}} p(A)+p(B)-p(A)p(B)$$

Comment: My mistake in using the incorrect terminology. This being so, I still maintain that $\sim R$ and $E$ are $\bf{mutually \ exclusive}$ events. As defined on page 10 of the paper, $\sim R$ is defined as ``I do not return to check my net in two weeks’ time" and $E$ is defined as: ``I'll find fish that are 10+ inches are in the net". This follows because it is not possible for someone to fail to check their net yet also $find$ fish in their net as 10+ inches.  Or do you dispute this? Do you at least grant that $if$ $R$ and $E$ are mutually exclusive events, then the equality holds?